# make polygons from points extracted by concave hull

Tags: polygon, autocad, boundary, concave-hull

I would like to make a file including polygon or lines from boundary points extracted from point cloud by concave hull method as shown in below page.

http://ait-survey.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/concave_hull_polygon1.png

Boundary points are 3D coordinates.

Also I would like to make polygon file import in AutoCAD.

Let me know how to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a interesting problem. I would start with:

1. Identify the outer circle around the points, as shown here: http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2011/02/creating-the-smallest-possible-circle-around-2d-autocad-geometry-using-net.html
2. Run through the circle degrees (0 to 2PI), find the closest point. That should give you the order of the points, counter-clockwise.
3. Draw the polyline

I do not have a code 'ready-to-use'... may have some time late this week. But what do you think about the approach?

Comment: It is a good idea. I think that  making polygon after ordering points is the best methodology, too. Moreover, it will easy to import to Autocad by saving as obj file of ordering points (vertices) and polygon (face). I am finding open source for ordering points or making a program for it. Let me know if there are open sources for processing like this.